# Trouble setting up database using phpMyAdmin and xampp

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working on creating a database for my website. I'm getting an error when trying to insert into the database from my live website. I'm not 100% clear on exactly how everything works and am uncertain where to start when fixing this error.

I think I might have missed something when installing/setting everything up, so I'll list the steps I took to set it up.

1. Installed xampp and set up a user / password for myself
2. Went to localhost and created my database (3dcontact) and table(contact)
3. Using filezilla uploaded my new contact.php page to my websites live server that contains the code to connect to the database.

I've followed many tutorials online (and have looked through stack overflow) to setup xampp, phpMyAdmin, and MySQL but still can't figure out a solution.

Here's the PHP code from contact.php (Anywhere you see "removed", the actual data has been removed for security reasons).

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    define('DB_NAME', 'removed');
    define('DB_USER', 'removed');
    define('DB_PW', 'removed');
    define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');

    if(!$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PW, DB_NAME)){
        echo "Unable to connect to database - Error: " . mysqli_error();
    } else {
        echo "Succesful";
    }

    //Name
    $FName = $_POST['FName'];
    $FName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $FName);
    $LName = $_POST['LName'];
    $LName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $LName);
    $Company = $_POST['Company'];
    $Company = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Company);

    //Phone
    $Phone1 = $_POST['Phone1'];
    $Fax = $_POST['Fax'];

    //Address
    $Street = $_POST['Street'];
    $Street = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Street);
    $City = $_POST['City'];
    $City = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $City);
    $State = $_POST['State'];
    $State = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $State);
    $Zip = $_POST['Zip'];
    $Zip = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Zip);
    $Country = $_POST['Country'];
    $Country = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Country);

    //Message
    $Message = $_POST['Message'];
    $Message = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Message);

    //Email
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Email);

    //Email
    $Email2 = $_POST['Email2'];
    $Email2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Email2);

    $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO `removed`.`removed`(`ID`, `FName`, `LName`, `Company`, `Phone`, `Fax`, `Street`, `City`, `State`, `Country`, `Zipcode`, `Email`, `SEmail`, `Message`) VALUES (NULL, '".$FName."', '".$LName."', '".$Company."', '".$Phone1."', '".$Fax."', '".$Street."', '".$City."', '".$State."', '".$Country."', '".$Zipcode."', '".$Email."', '".$Email2."', '".$Message."')";

    if(!mysqli_real_query($link, $sqlInsert)){
        echo "Failed To Post To Database";
    } else {
        mysqli_close($link);
        echo "Posted To Database!" . mysqli_error();    
    }
```

When submitting the form, "Unable to connect to database - Error: Failed To Post To Database" No mysqli error is appearing.

Any help, ideas, or anything really is very appreciated I'm out of ideas to fix this.

Comment: try using localhost instead of 127.0.0.1. Also, did you create this db on your live server?.

You can use this link here to install xampp,mysql,phpmyadmin all in one shot https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: I've tried using localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 and it still gives me the same error. Also I'm slightly confused by your question, I created the database by going to localhost (which lead to xampp) and going to phpMyAdmin from localhost. In phpMyAdmin I created the database and table. Not sure if that's creating the db on the live server.

Comment: well you said you uploaded the file to your server, When you create a local db on your computer, that does not create it on your server at your hosting company.

Comment: I uploaded the contact.php file to my server but haven't uploaded any xampp, phpMyAdmin, or MySQL files to the server. Where can I find the db file I created using phpMyAdmin? Also is there a specific place to upload the file to or is the root directory fine?

Comment: where do i start :). Basically you need to do the same thing you did at home (xampp) on your live server. So your hosting company should have you login, then you may have a cpanel control panel where you will find phpmyadmin, you need to create the db again and populate it with the info from home. 

Xampp is a package that does it all, so you dont even need to upload that file to a server to test it, save it in your "htdocs" folder then open a browser and type in "localhost"

Try this: http://www.endoflinemagazine.com/2013/11/xampp-how-to-move-from-local-to-webserver.html

Comment: Sorry I'm a nooby when it comes to databases! Thanks for the help so far, I'm going to follow the tutorial you linked and I'll let you know in a few if it all works.

Comment: No problem man, we were all noobs once :)